# Not showing image in jsp

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

I have jsp:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- main data -->
    <c:forEach items="${itemsList}" var="item">

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"><a
                href="<c:out value="${item.link}" />"><c:out
                value="${item.title}" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"><c:out
            value="${item.pubDate}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"><c:out
            value="${item.description}" /></td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

When showing value item.description in browser it parses as String and not as image.

```
String description="<img align="left" vspace="5" hspace="10" src="http://kor.ill.in.ua/m/190x120/1621767.jpg"> infoinfo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `<c:out>` does: it escapes HTML special characters. If you trust the description to contain safe HTML, and want to have the HTML code as is in the page, then don't use `<c:out>`:

```
<td align="center" colspan="3">${item.description}</td>
```